# TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

Tags: opencv, python-3.7

I am trying to set up my detector for a face recognition project or a program, but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Also I tried with changing:

`cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x, y + h), font, 255)`

to

`cv2.putText(img, name, (x, y + h), font, 2, (0, 255, 0), 2)`

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

rec = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
rec.read("trainer/training_data.yml")
id=0
font=(cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,1,0,1)

while(True):
    ret,img=cam.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        id,conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        cv2.putText(img,str(id),(x,y+h),font,255)
    cv2.imshow("FACEDETECTIONPT1",img)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Comment: `cv2.putText(img, name, (x, y + h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)`

Comment: @AmanRelan, if my answer helped, please accept. Otherwise please add a comment so that we can understand how to better solve your issue.

Comment: @SunnyPatel sir, i tried your thing but it still showed the same error but then instead i removed the parameters from the font and edited my putText to `cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)` and this seems to have worked for me.. but even then a big thanks to you sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed the parameters from the font and edited my putText to `cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)` and this seems to have worked for me..

Answer (score 27):

In my experience the error statement was misleading. In my case, the coordinates (x, y) were in `float` instead of `int` and fixing that fixed this issue.

Comment: I had precisely the same issue! This error message should definitely be fixed in opencv.

Comment: still to this day this issue is not fixed

Answer (score 9):

Another possible reason for this misleading error message is if the `img` is a view into `np.ndarray`, not contiguous memory data. So e.g. if your code worked with `img`, it will fail if you do something like `img=np.flipud(img)`.

The solution is to make deep copy, like `img=np.flipud(img).copy()`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have discussed, this error is misleading. I received this error when I tried applying open cv functions on an image that was opened with `PIL`

For example:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2

# error if we use PIL to read image and apply cv2 functions
image = Image.open(path)
cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

# resolve error by reading image with cv2
image = cv2.imread(path)
cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by entering Thickness in **int** instead of **float**

For eg,
I changed this

```
cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])), (int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])), color, 0.6 )
```

to

```
cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])), (int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])), color, 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [`putText` documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext), I see that your `font` is a tuple, and you're trying to fill in multiple parameters for `putText`: `fontFace`, `fontScale`, `color`, `thickness`, and `lineType`.

Perhaps you can [unpack that parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to get what you need (with the * operator):

```
cv2.putText(img, name, (x, y + h), *font, 2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

cv2.putText(img, name, (x, y + h), font, 2, color, 2) 
and the color should be mentioned in RGB format  
for example : (255,255,255)

i think this should help you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I resolved it. The message can arise from different types of errors but the content of the message is not what it says actually.

In my case, I read the image using PIL and tried to apply openCV operations on it which lead to this problem. You must have to use `cv2.imread(image_path)` to draw rectangle using `cv2.rectangle()`. Another reason to this error can be when your point coordinates are in float or double instead of integers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the PIL image had a mode of 'P' stands for palettised. I converted it into RGB & now the error is gone.